# Geometry Nodes Atribute Math

Tags: geometry, geometry-nodes

I am making Building and i am trying to Change the Window Corner into WallCorner [image: Red Circle Wall Corner into Window Corner]

Comment: you could use the index to do this. if you provide your blend file, i will show you.

Comment: https://we.tl/t-8fBmc0unNX blend file

Comment: thank you. what blender version are u using?

Answer (score 2):

This is NOT the complete solution, just a "push" to the right direction. If you still have question, ask in the comments.

[image]

You already had the right idea with the "Point Separate" node.

You put in there your value WallCorner.

I just filled that with some "useful" value.

So i got your px and pz value and compared these to some "fixed" values, put that in two other values (WallMask1 +2) and then i multiplied these two values.

Because the Attribute Compare nodes outputs a true(1) or false(0) we can multiply both values to get a logical AND result for the WallCorner. If both conditions are true, the Mask will be True  and so it works:

[image]

So this is the principle.

> NOTE: Of course you shouldn't compare to fixed values, but to computed
> values in relation to your grid length and width!

Here the modified blend file:

[image]

Comment: Thank you but how achieved legacy nodes in blender 3.0 also now blender 2.93.7 cant read those nodes

Comment: i got point i just didn't knew that was possible way to make it